# File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc used in temporary directory

Tags: c#, windows

If `File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc` is applied in user temporary directory, then it sets to 1-2 seconds different modified time than specified. On `LastWriteTime` is properly applied timezone (difference in hours), but strange difference in seconds is there as well.

Example:

```
using System.IO;

string tempDir = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
// required new last write datetime 2012-12-05 15:50:15
DateTime newLastWriteTimeUtc = new DateTime(2012, 12, 5, 15, 50, 15, 0);
string testFilePath = Path.Combine(tempDir, "Test.txt");
if (File.Exists(testFilePath))
{
  File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(testFilePath, newLastWriteTimeUtc);
  FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(testFilePath);
  // you get real datetime 2012-12-05 15:50:16
  DateTime lastWriteTimeUtc = fInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc;
}
```

Can anyone give an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: FAT32 file system time stamp resolution is 2 seconds.  Good match for what you see.  If it is actually NTFS then mistrust the kind of software that wants to mess with file access.  Like anti-malware.